# Added a second office to the page with address schema for both and original business listing ranks worse

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, google-my-business

I have a site which has recently grown and have a second office. They have registered for business listings (so they tell me) but their business listing has dropped.

As well as having an individual Google map for each office, I have added `schema.org/PostalAddress` too. Originally this was as one address but now I have it as

```
<section class="a" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <h2>Visit us</h2>
    <p>
        <strong> Office 1</strong> <br />
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Add 1 </span> <br />
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Locality 1<br /></span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Region 1</span><br /> UK
        <a href="tel:1111111"><span itemprop="telephone">1111111</span></a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong> Office 2</strong><br />
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Add 2</span> <br />
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Locality 2<br /></span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Region 2</span><br /> UK
        <a href="tel:2222222"><span itemprop="telephone">2222222</span></a>
    </p>
    <ul class="b">
        <li><a href="/visitus" class="button">Visit us</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

So all I have done is replicated the `<p>` tag for office 1 and gave done it for office 2.

Does anyone know if this is OK or would this cause a business listings drop? Before any changes the business listing had it listed at # 1 or 3 but now its 7 or 8th place.

Comment: There is always seems to be some level of disruption when content changes. I would not expect that adding another address would make a difference. Dropping to lower on the first page should not scare you. Make sure that in Google My Business (GMB) you add your new office. Google compares NAP (name, address, phone) between GMB and the website. Otherwise, just be patient. It will all work out okay. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely your structured data has any direct bearing on ranking, with or without your changes. Google's John Mueller [has said](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/980902538865205248) there is "no generic ranking boost for SD usage", but it can "make it easier to show" a page when it's relevant.

Moreover, the code in your question has some issues.

First, I think each address should be a separate instance of `PostalAddress` (see Example 7 at https://schema.org/PostalAddress, for instance). What you've done validates but actually provides a single address with multiples of each value, as opposed to two distinct addresses.

Second, while Google may consume that structured data it doesn't trigger any documented search feature. Google's [local business markup](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business), for instance, requires more than just the address.

Comment: So are you suggesting having 2 instances of itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" for each address?

Answer (score 1):

To start, what page or area of the site are you adding this new set of data?

I would imagine that adding a second set of NAP info on the page the original location was on could have made it less clear which location that page was meant for.

Ideally, you want to have a page for each location, and the related structured data on each page.

Finally, as you asked in a comment above, yes, you should have a separate itemtype in order to differentiate the itemprops for each location. The output from your code (via Structured Data Testing Tool) does not help distinguish information for each location:
[image]

Consider the relationships between the sets of structured data. It's best to create connections by nesting pieces together to help search engines understand all the data you are providing. 
I try to avoid microdata and simply add a JSON script to satisfy the structured data for the entity. This makes it easier to nest data, as seen in the code and output below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org/",
  "@type":"Organization",
  "logo":"http://example.com/logo.jpg",
  "legalname":"BUSINESS NAME",
  "url":"http://example.com/",
  "address":
[
  {
  "@type":"PostalAddress",
  "streetAddress":"ADDRESS",
  "addressLocality":"CITY",
  "addressRegion":"STATE",
  "postalCode":"ZIP",
  "addressCountry":"USA"
  },
  {
  "@type":"PostalAddress",
  "streetAddress":"ADDRESS",
  "addressLocality":"CITY",
  "addressRegion":"STATE",
  "postalCode":"ZIP",
  "addressCountry":"USA"
  }]}
  </script>
```

[image]